# customize vuejs datepicker for bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, vue.js, vuejs2

Currently [vuejs datepicker for boostrap 3](https://uiv.wxsm.space/date-picker) looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, we have a label `2018 April`. What I need is to change that label into `April 2018`.

I saw that the component doesn't have any API reference that can help me with that. Any ideas?

My solution would be to find a way to modify the plugin but that is the last solution.

Answer (score 2):

indeed, you can't. From the source code of your plugin: https://github.com/wxsms/uiv/blob/master/src/components/datepicker/DateView.vue

`2018 April` is coded as `<b>{{yearMonthStr}}</b>`. This is a computed property defined as follow:

```
yearMonthStr () {
    return isExist(this.month) ? `${this.year} ${this.t(`uiv.datePicker.month${this.month + 1}`)}` : this.year
},
```

So as you say, it's complicated and you might have to modify the plugin. You could make a pull request to the project adding an option to the component to customize the month.